# hibernate теряет соединение

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Здравствуйте. Моя java программа периодически падает, примерно через день или два после запуска.

вот логи самой программы.

```
21.08.16 12:28:47 [ERROR] com.dao.Dao - could not extract ResultSet
21.08.16 12:28:47 [ERROR] com.main.Program - org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
```

к сожалению не могу дать более полный лог, потому что ошибка пишется в логи методом toString().

вот server.log глассфиша:

```
[2016-08-21T12:28:47.905+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=1065 _ThreadName=Thread-64] [timeMillis: 1471771727905] [levelValue: 900] [[
  SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01]]

[2016-08-21T12:28:47.906+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [ERROR] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=1065 _ThreadName=Thread-64] [timeMillis: 1471771727906] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  The last packet successfully received from the server was 36,940,570 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 36,940,570 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.]]
```

autoReconnect=true   я уже дописал, но толку это особого не дало.
Вот полная (и вся в общем-то) конфигурация hibernate

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>   
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">123</property>
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина падения программы.

Comment: `autoReconnect=true` - не надёжное решение. Лучше использовать пул соединений с автоматической проверкой соединения перед взятием из пула и с периодическим автоматическим обновлением (переподключением) соединений.

Comment: Сделаете себе примерно такое, что написано в ответе на этот вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766023/hibernate-failed-to-execute-query-afte-1-day